# Place points in a normal distribution

Tags: python, numpy

I need to place points distributed normally between 0 and an r max which is 0.00174.
I want to have the points x coordinate to be smaller at the beginning and larger at the end.

My code makes circles that have different radii till rmax and places them evenly (in this case 10 points per circle) around the origin. The r values are linear right now but I want the radii to increase exponentially where the points are closer together in beginning and farther apart at the end.

```
points = 120
rmax = 0.001745
ppa = 10 #number of points per annulie
valuesr = np.linspace(0.00001,rmax,int(points/ppa))
pirange = np.linspace(0.00001,2*np.pi,int(ppa))
x = np.array([])
y = np.array([])
for r in valuesr:
    for theta in pirange:
        x=np.append(x,r*np.cos(theta))
        y=np.append(y,r*np.sin(theta))
plt.scatter(x,y,marker=".",lw=0.01)
```

Comment: What are mean and standard deviation of the normal distribution you want? Your minimum value (0) and maximum value (0.00174) are at what Z-scores? If you know these, you can use `scipy.stats.truncnorm` [(documentation here)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html) to generate a truncated normal distribution for the `r_max` values. Also, when you say you want to generate points between `0` and `r_max`, do you mean points in a square with corners at `(0, 0)` and `(r_max, r_max)`? Or do you just want numbers between `0` and `r_max`?

Comment: @AJH I just need numbers between 0 and rmax. What i meant by normal distribution is that the points at 0,0 should be closer together than points at the r_max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can do this by using `np.logspace`; So, by changing `valuesr` to:

```
valuesr = np.logspace(np.log(0.00001), np.log(rmax), int(points / ppa), base=np.exp(1))
```

The resulted image will be as:

[image: exponential]